# UiLifecycleHelper not opening Facebook Session

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I have Facebook Login integrated in the native android app which im creating.The UiLifecycleHelper class which opens Facebook Session was working fine before ,but suddenly the session is not getting opened and The Session.StatusCallback is not getting triggered and onSessionStateChange() method is not getting called.

```
public class SessionActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static final int SIGNUP = 0;
private static final int CITYLIST = 1;
private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = CITYLIST+1;
private boolean isResumed = false;


private Fragment[] fragments = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];

private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
private Session.StatusCallback callback = 
    new Session.StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, 
            SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UiLifecycle is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);


    }
};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "UiLifecycle is not called",      Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_session);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragments[SIGNUP] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.SignupFragment);
    fragments[CITYLIST] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.CityListFragment);
    fragments[SETTINGS] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.userSettingsFragment);


     FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
    }
    transaction.commit();

}


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    uiHelper.onResume();
    isResumed = true;
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    uiHelper.onPause();
    isResumed = false;
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
   uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    uiHelper.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}   

private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "showFragment is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        if (i == fragmentIndex) {
            transaction.show(fragments[i]);
        } else {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
    }
    if (addToBackStack) {
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}


private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
    // Only make changes if the activity is visible
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onSessionStateChange is called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (isResumed) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        // Get the number of entries in the back stack
        int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        // Clear the back stack
        for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
            manager.popBackStack();
        }
        if (state.equals(SessionState.OPENED)) {
            // If the session state is open:
            // Show the authenticated fragment
            showFragment(CITYLIST, false);

        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            // If the session state is closed:
            // Show the login fragment
            showFragment(SIGNUP, false);
        }
    }

   }

@Override
protected void onResumeFragments() {
    super.onResumeFragments();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onResumeFragments is called" + session.isOpened(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        // if the session is already open,
        // try to show the selection fragment
        showFragment(CITYLIST, false);
    } else {
        // otherwise present the splash screen
        // and ask the person to login.
        showFragment(SIGNUP, false);
    }
}

}
```

**Question**

Why UILifeCycleHelper helper is not opening new FB session and opening the intended fragment(CityListFragment) ?

**Info**

The code was working fine before ,where the Session was opened and token was created and after i made some edits its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to use the Facebook login button in another activity through which i started the SessionActivity.The reason i dint want to use the fb login button in the SessionActivity is that I wanted the user to click the login button in another activity to enter the SessionActivity.I solved this by using the Fb loginbutton in the SessionActivity's onCreate() method,by hiding it and performed the click through by using performclick() method(Since the user has already pressed a custom button in the other activity i used).Now a new Session got opened.

```
LoginButton loginBtn;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   loginBtn = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_profile_activity_button);
   loginBtn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   loginBtn.performClick();


    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragments[SIGNUP] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.signup_fragment);
    fragments[CITYLIST] = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.citylist_fragment);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
        transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
```